# Why javax.servlet.jsp.JspContext is an abstract class

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jsp-tags

Why this is not an interface, am I missing something?

```
public abstract class JspContext {
    public abstract void setAttribute(String var1, Object var2);
    public abstract void setAttribute(String var1, Object var2, int var3);
    public abstract Object getAttribute(String var1);
    public abstract Object getAttribute(String var1, int var2);
    public abstract Object findAttribute(String var1);
    public abstract void removeAttribute(String var1);
    public abstract void removeAttribute(String var1, int var2);
    public abstract int getAttributesScope(String var1);
    public abstract Enumeration<String> getAttributeNamesInScope(int var1);
    public abstract JspWriter getOut();
    public abstract ExpressionEvaluator getExpressionEvaluator();
    public abstract ELContext getELContext();
    public abstract VariableResolver getVariableResolver();

    public JspWriter pushBody(Writer writer) {
        return null;
    }

    public JspWriter popBody() {
        return null;
    }
```

}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17370014/3959856. And if you look at the bottom of this page http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/javax.servlet/javax.servlet.jsp/2.2.0/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.java .you'll see two hook methods. maybe they are the reason.

Comment: So it doesn't answer my question, the two concrete methods are just empty methods which shall be overridden properly and other methods are abstract. So why it is not an interface?

Comment: well the difference is that abstract methods Must be implemented, hooks don't. I am guessing here that's the reason. Abstract classes were more popular before as well..

Comment: @JackFlamp I know the difference of abstract and concrete methods, and .... The overall code reuse provided by these 2 concrete methods is just a little (and in maybe in just a few implementing classes), and most of other implementing classes shall override the method. I believe this is just a bad design and code smell from JSR people.